# Passing a structure/class reference of reference to a function

Tags: c++, reference

I am newbie in C++ and need some help. 
I want take a reference passed to a functon  and pass it to another function. This reference is passed to the function encapsulated into another structure/class:

1. I defined a

   ```
   Class A {
      int ax;
      int ay;
   };
   ```
2. I defined a:

   ```
   Class B
   {
      int bx;
      int by;
      A: a;
   };
   ```
3. I defined a function : `f1(B& arg)`

Now, let's say `aa` is an object of type `A`:
I want to pass `aa` as reference to function `f1`, but inside the `class B`.
Something like this :

```
B bb;
bb.b1=10
bb.b2=20
bb.a=aa ==> here I want reference to a 

call f1(*bb)
```

But reference is take from another function so the finla stuff is:

```
caller::f2(&A arg)
{
  B bb;
    bb.b1=10
    bb.b2=20
    bb.a=arg==> here I want reference to a 

    call f1(*bb)

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I've put in a couple of statement terminators. C++ ain't Java :-) But your question is unclear. What is `A: a;` And what is type `AA`? Don't you want a reference to **A**?

Comment: What's `A: a;`? Did you mean `A a;`?

Comment: Why not write a function that takes `A&`? If the function needs a `B` for processing, pass a `B` as well.

Comment: This looks a lot like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). (That is, you were attempting to solve a problem, and that solution doesn't work, and now you're trying to solve "the problem of the non-working solution" instead of coming up with a different solution to the original problem.)

Comment: @ Batsheba- -Yes . my mistake it is A

Comment: @Angew yes it is A a

Comment: @molbdnilo: the structure is a wrapper for parameters to pass to function f1. Something like a DTO. So  i can't change the signature of f1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want pass aa as reference to function f1, but inside the class B

Then you need to make `a` a reference variable (with `&`):

```
A& a;
```

References need to be explicitly initialized, so you need to provide a constructor for `B` to do that:

```
class B
{
    public:
    B(A& a) : a(a) {} // constructor, to make `a` refer to the given parameter

    int bx;
    int by;
    A& a;
};
```

Now you can do this:

```
B bb(aa); // passes `aa` to B's constructor
bb.b1 = 10;
bb.b2 = 20;
```

and call `f1` with `bb`: `f1(bb);` and `f1` will gain access to `aa` via `bb.a`.

---

Alternatively, if you want `a` to be able to refer to "nothing", you can make it a pointer, so that it can be a null pointer. References must always refer to valid variables. But that doesn't seem to be what you need here so I left it out for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: More or less it is what i was looking for, but may be i have to be more Clair about the real goal. Now i'll try to be add some details.

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize your reference when you declare it.
and you cannot change your "reference" once your initialize it.
you only can change the variable you reference to.

so you have two way to solve this:
add a constructor

```
class A {
    int ax;
    int ay;
};

class B
{
    B(A& v) : a(v) {}
    int bx;
    int by;
    A& a;
};
```

OR

change your reference to pointer;

Comment: @=xFFFFFFF: More or less it is what i was looking for, but may be i have to be more Clair about the real goal. Now i'll try to be add some details.